# Reading/writing struct containing a variable-size 2D array using C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, struct, binaryfiles

I am rewriting some VB code in C# and am struggling a bit with a binary write/read operation. I have got a structure (equivalent to VB UDT) which contains a header and a variable-size 2D array. The row and column count is stored in the header.

Possibly I should be using an object rather than a struct, but I think that is a different discussion and unless it is a really bad idea I would prefer to stick with the struct for now.

I have done this sort of thing using VB many times and it is accomplished in a few lines of code. What I would generally do is something like this...

To write:
1) Dump UDT to a binary file with a Put statement.

To read:
1) Get the row and column counts from the file header using Get statements
2) Dim UDT and size the array part using the column/row counts found above
3) Read file contents into variable using a Get statement

My C# version is currently something like this:

```
using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open( [filename] ,FileMode.Open)))
{

  // Read number of rows and columns...
  byte[] buff = b.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GridStructHeader))); // read byte array
  GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buff, GCHandleType.Pinned); // protect buffer from GC
  //Marshal the bytes...
  GridStructHeader h = 
    (GridStructHeader)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
    typeof(GridStructHeader));
  handle.Free(); // give control of the buffer back to the GC 

  // Create structure...
  GridStruct grd = new GridStruct();
  grd.Cell = new GridCell[h.NumCols, h.NumRows];

  // Read grid into memory...
  buff = b.ReadBytes(Marshal.SizeOf(grd)); // size buffer to match structure
  handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buff, GCHandleType.Pinned);
  grd = (GridStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
    typeof(GridStruct));
  handle.Free();

}
```

GridStruct is a struct containing the header and 2D data array. The relevant part of it looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
struct GridStruct
{
  public int NumCols;
  public int NumRows;
  public GridCell[,] Cell;
}
```

GridStructHeader is a data type used for convenience here, and contains only the first part of the header. I am using this as a way of reading the row and column count (both Int data type). I initially tried to do this using ReadInt32() to read the values individually, but this wasn't working and I put it down to Serialization.

GridStructHeader contains the row and column count (and some other fields, omitted here for simplicity)

```
[Serializable]
struct GridStructHeader
{
  public int NumCols;
  public int NumRows;
}
```

GridCell is a struct containing the contents of each cell in the grid (AKA matrix AKA 2D array).

When I run the above I am getting an AccessViolation exception at the line

```
grd = (GridStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(GridStruct));
```

My methodology is not quite right, I think. If anyone can advise how best to do this it would be appreciated. It doesn't have to be super-fast, particularly. Clarity and brevity of code are of higher priority.

Comment: What are the actual contents of `GridStructHeader`? `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` might have a problem with `GridStruct` because it contains the non-primitive type `GridCell`. 
This might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clyon/2004/09/17/gchandles-boxing-and-heap-corruption/

Comment: I have edited my question to include the contents of GridStructHeader.